# html javascript chage the value of my <div> but refresh the page for 1 second and then is all null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, hidden

I am try to display under my form the new value.

```
    <form>
    <h2>AES Encryption</h2>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <label for="inputValue">Text to encrypt</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" id="inputValue" size="50" name="inputValue" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
  <label for="inputPassword">Password:</label>
  </td>
  <td>
  <input type="text" id="inputPassword" size="50" name="inputPassword" />
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <input type="submit" value="Verschlüsseln" id="submitButton" onclick="encryptAES()"/>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="afterPressed" hidden="true">
<h3 id="resultTitle"></h3>
<p id="result"></p>
<br>

<h3>Code</h3>
<a href="sampleAES.zip" download="sampleAES.zip">Download</a>


</div>

</form>
```

and my Script:

```
function encryptAES() {
    var value = document.getElementById("inputValue").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("inputPassword").value;
    var encrypted = base64toHEX(CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, password));
    document.getElementById("afterPressed").removeAttribute("hidden");
    document.getElementById("resultTitle").innerHTML = "Result";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = encrypted;
}
```

When I click the button the code works for 1 second and then refresh the form  as null
I want to show the result in the div result tag, but the page is updated and everything disappears and the code is hidden again.

Comment: You need to prevent the form from submitting, something alogn the lins of `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is submitting, so the values are displayed in the browser and then the page reloads.

You can either set the `onsubmit` property of the form like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

Or you can use an `<input type="button">` or `<button>` instead of the `<input type="submit">` that is... well, **submit**ting the form.

Answer (score 0):

Update your form tag with `<form onsubmit="return false;">`. This will prevent the page from getting submitted.